# How to say that a sentence is a result of a certain event

Tags: usage

How should one say in English that an event has caused another event to happen in the form of a sentence (the resultant event coming in sentence form). For example, I want to write that resource limitations have had the result that besides investment development, increase in investment efficiency also becomes greatly important. I wish to write this in a more concise and more formal way.
Already, I tried the following:

> limitation in resources has resulted in investment efficiency becoming very important in addition to investment development.

Comment: *Limited resources have **led to** investment efficiency becoming  important as well as investment development*. But unless your intended audience are already very familiar with exactly what you mean by ***investment efficiency*** and ***investment development*** (I'm not) they'll probably find the whole statement rather confusing, however you fiddle about with the surrounding syntax. I suggest you use less jargon.

Comment: Could also be "A limitation in resources has resulted..."

Comment: What is "investment development"? And by "resources" do you mean "investment resources", i.e. "money to invest"?  Are you trying to say that when funds for investment are limited, it is just as important to invest in vehicles with a high rate of return as it is to diversify?

Comment: @TRomano I do not really know what investment development is. Probably, it would be better to use development of investment. This is a translation you know, but generally, I mean resource limitation has made investment efficiency as important as development of investment.

Answer (score 1):

You might try:

> Limitation of resources has made both investment development and investment efficiency increasingly important.

Or:

> Both investment development and investment efficiency are increasingly important due to resource limitations.

Or:

> Resource limitations have magnified the importance not only of investment development, but also of investment efficiency.